# Optimizing model lookups in django

Tags: django, django-views

I have a ToDo model, which represents a task. Each task belongs to an organization, a team within that organization, and a staff.

This is how I filter tasks, in the views:

```
def task_list(request, param=None, param_id=None):
    if param == "org":
        tasks = ToDo.objects.filter(org__id = param_id).exclude(todo_status=4)
    elif param == "orgstaff":
        tasks = ToDo.objects.filter(assigned_to__id = param_id).exclude(todo_status=4)
    elif param == "orgteam":
        tasks = ToDo.objects.filter(team__id = param_id).exclude(todo_status=4)
    return render(request, "task_list.html", {"tasks":tasks})
```

Is there a way, I could create dicts, and replace these the above 6 lines into 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dict and [dict unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
def task_list(request, param=None, param_id=None):
    field_mapping = {'org': 'org__id', 'orgstaff': 'assigned_to__id', 'orgteam': 'team__id'}
    tasks = ToDo.objects.filter(**{field_mapping[param]: param_id}).exclude(todo_status=4)
    return render(request, "task_list.html", {"tasks":tasks})
```

Comment: could you please explain a little - `**{field_mapping[param]: param_id}`. Thanks for the answer. Specifically what the ** does?

Comment: @user1629366, `add(**{'a': 1, 'b': 2})` is similar to `add(a=1, b=2)`. I recommend you to read [Unpacking argument list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) from Python tutorial.